# How do these two \vspace implementations differ?

Tags: spacing

I'm building my resume in LaTeX and the template I'm using some ideas from defined an environment like such:

```
\newenvironment{body} {
    \vspace*{-16pt}
    \begin{changemargin}{-0.25in}{-0.5in}
  } 
    {\end{changemargin}
}
```

And whenever I start a portion of my resume (a section, that is) I start with `\begin{body}`. However, for spacing issues I always have `\vspace{14pt}` after every `\begin{body}` (and right before `\end{body}` which just seems asinine if I can make it part of the environment. So I changed it to:

```
\newenvironment{body} {
    \vspace*{-2pt}
    \begin{changemargin}{-0.25in}{-0.5in}
  } 
    {\end{changemargin}
    \vspace{14pt}
}
```

Is this correct in that it yields the same result?

Also, what does the `\vspace*` do as compared to `\vspace`?

Comment: For the second question, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/76106/21591.

Answer (score 3):

It is impossible to say given the amount of information posted.

You are missing some `%` at ends of lines

```
\newenvironment{body} {%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \vspace*{-16pt}%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \begin{changemargin}{-0.25in}{-0.5in}%%%%%%%%%%%%
  } 
    {\end{changemargin}%%%%%%%%%%%%%
}
```

But any negative space, -16pt or -2pt will in principle cause this environment to over-print the previous text. If it doesn't then something you haven't shown is adding space to prevent that.

Normally it is better to use `\addvspace` in such situations. Most LaTeX display environments use this: Two `\addvspace` one after the other just add the maximum of the two values rather than the sum, so it avoids getting too much space if one display environment follows another.