# beamer: content top and bottom margins

Tags: beamer, margins

It is trivial to modify the left and right margins in beamer.

But what about the top and bottom?

If possible, I would like to reduce a little bit that top margin, marked with the hand-drawn red arrow:

[image: screenshot]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}

\setbeamersize{text margin left=0.5em, text margin right=0.5em}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{\color{black}\bfseries\insertframetitle\par\vskip-6pt\hrulefill}

\newcommand\FourQuad[4]{
    \colorbox{yellow}{\begin{minipage}[b][.40\textheight][t]{.49\textwidth}#1\end{minipage}}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}[b][.40\textheight][t]{.49\textwidth}#2\end{minipage}\\
    \begin{minipage}[b][.40\textheight][t]{.49\textwidth}#3\end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}[b][.40\textheight][t]{.49\textwidth}#4\end{minipage}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{A frame divided in four quadrants}
\FourQuad%
{First quadrant contents and some more text text text text more text text text text more text text text text more text text text text more text text text text more text text text text more text text text text}%
{
  \centering
  \rule{3cm}{2cm}
  A test figure.
}%
{\begin{align*}
  a &= b \\
  &= c \\
  & = d.
\end{align*}}%
{Fourth quadrant contents and some more text text text text more text text text text more text text text text more text text text text more text text text text more text text text text more text text text text}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I found that \beamer@frametopsklip is set by the frame command, so cannot be globally reset.  For \begin{frame}[t] it uses \beamer@frametopskip=.2cm plus .5\paperheight\relax%.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want to do this only for your "quad"-frame or globally? For only this special frame, a quick hack would be to simply insert `\vspace{}`

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}

\setbeamersize{text margin left=0.5em, text margin right=0.5em}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{\color{black}\bfseries\insertframetitle\par\vskip-6pt\hrulefill}

\newcommand\FourQuad[4]{
        \vspace*{-0.2cm}
    \colorbox{yellow}{\begin{minipage}[b][.40\textheight][t]{.49\textwidth}#1\end{minipage}}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}[b][.40\textheight][t]{.49\textwidth}#2\end{minipage}\\
    \begin{minipage}[b][.40\textheight][t]{.49\textwidth}#3\end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}[b][.40\textheight][t]{.49\textwidth}#4\end{minipage}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{A frame divided in four quadrants}
\FourQuad%
{First quadrant contents and some more text text text text more text text text text more text text text text more text text text text more text text text text more text text text text more text text text text}%
{
  \centering
  \rule{3cm}{2cm}
  A test figure.
}%
{\begin{align*}
  a &= b \\
  &= c \\
  & = d.
\end{align*}}%
{Fourth quadrant contents and some more text text text text more text text text text more text text text text more text text text text more text text text text more text text text text more text text text text}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**EDIT:**

To make this hack globally, add the `\vspace{}` to the frametitle template

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}

\setbeamersize{text margin left=0.5em, text margin right=0.5em}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{\color{black}\bfseries\insertframetitle\par\vskip-6pt\hrulefill \vspace*{-0.2cm}}

\newcommand\FourQuad[4]{
    \colorbox{yellow}{\begin{minipage}[b][.40\textheight][t]{.49\textwidth}#1\end{minipage}}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}[b][.40\textheight][t]{.49\textwidth}#2\end{minipage}\\
    \begin{minipage}[b][.40\textheight][t]{.49\textwidth}#3\end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}[b][.40\textheight][t]{.49\textwidth}#4\end{minipage}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{A frame divided in four quadrants}
\FourQuad%
{First quadrant contents and some more text text text text more text text text text more text text text text more text text text text more text text text text more text text text text more text text text text}%
{
  \centering
  \rule{3cm}{2cm}
  A test figure.
}%
{\begin{align*}
  a &= b \\
  &= c \\
  & = d.
\end{align*}}%
{Fourth quadrant contents and some more text text text text more text text text text more text text text text more text text text text more text text text text more text text text text more text text text text}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You could also use \makeatletter
\newcommand\FourQuad[4]{\vskip-\beamer@frametopskip ...

Comment: This will do it. But do you have a suggestion to make it global?

Comment: @RicardoCruz See the edit

Comment: I tried out this solution. Why is the asterisk at `\vspace*` needed? With the asterisk the solution works, without it it doesn't work.

Comment: @Viesturs see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/76106/36296 for an exaplanation