# Modifying the margins of all slides in Beamer

Tags: beamer, margins

I have difficulty with setting a standard margins from the left and right side in the Beamer. Any help is appreciated.

This template has been downloaded from:

> http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation> {
\usetheme{Madrid}
}

\usepackage{graphicx} % Allows including images
\usepackage{booktabs} % Allows the use of \toprule, \midrule and \bottomrule in tables

\title[Short title]{Full Title of the Talk} % The short title appears at the bottom of every slide, the full title is only on the title page

\author{John Smith} % Your name
\institute[UCLA] % Your institution as it will appear on the bottom of every slide, may be shorthand to save space
{
University of California \\ % Your institution for the title page
\medskip
\textit{john@smith.com} % Your email address
}
\date{\today} % Date, can be changed to a custom date

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage % Print the title page as the first slide
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Overview} % Table of contents slide, comment this block out to remove it
\tableofcontents % Throughout your presentation, if you choose to use \section{} and \subsection{} commands, these will automatically be printed on this slide as an overview of your presentation
\end{frame}

\subsection{Subsection Example} % A subsection can be created just before a set of slides with a common theme to further break down your presentation into chunks

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Paragraphs of Text}
Sed iaculis dapibus gravida. Morbi sed tortor erat, nec interdum arcu. Sed id lorem lectus. Quisque viverra augue id sem ornare non aliquam nibh tristique. Aenean in ligula nisl. Nulla sed tellus ipsum. Donec vestibulum ligula non lorem vulputate fermentum accumsan neque mollis.\\~\\

Sed diam enim, sagittis nec condimentum sit amet, ullamcorper sit amet libero. Aliquam vel dui orci, a porta odio. Nullam id suscipit ipsum. Aenean lobortis commodo sem, ut commodo leo gravida vitae. Pellentesque vehicula ante iaculis arcu pretium rutrum eget sit amet purus. Integer ornare nulla quis neque ultrices lobortis. Vestibulum ultrices tincidunt libero, quis commodo erat ullamcorper id.
\end{frame}

%------------------------------------------------

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Bullet Points}
\begin{itemize}
\item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
\item Aliquam blandit faucibus nisi, sit amet dapibus enim tempus eu
\item Nulla commodo, erat quis gravida posuere, elit lacus lobortis est, quis porttitor odio mauris at libero
\item Nam cursus est eget velit posuere pellentesque
\item Vestibulum faucibus velit a augue condimentum quis convallis nulla gravida
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

%------------------------------------------------

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Blocks of Highlighted Text}
\begin{block}{Block 1}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer lectus nisl, ultricies in feugiat rutrum, porttitor sit amet augue. Aliquam ut tortor mauris. Sed volutpat ante purus, quis accumsan dolor.
\end{block}

\begin{block}{Block 2}
Pellentesque sed tellus purus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Vestibulum quis magna at risus dictum tempor eu vitae velit.
\end{block}

\begin{block}{Block 3}
Suspendisse tincidunt sagittis gravida. Curabitur condimentum, enim sed venenatis rutrum, ipsum neque consectetur orci, sed blandit justo nisi ac lacus.
\end{block}
\end{frame}

%------------------------------------------------

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Multiple Columns}
\begin{columns}[c] % The "c" option specifies centered vertical alignment while the "t" option is used for top vertical alignment

\column{.45\textwidth} % Left column and width
\textbf{Heading}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Statement
\item Explanation
\item Example
\end{enumerate}

\column{.5\textwidth} % Right column and width
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer lectus nisl, ultricies in feugiat rutrum, porttitor sit amet augue. Aliquam ut tortor mauris. Sed volutpat ante purus, quis accumsan dolor.

\end{columns}
\end{frame}

%------------------------------------------------
\section{Second Section}
%------------------------------------------------

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Table}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{l l l}
\toprule
\textbf{Treatments} & \textbf{Response 1} & \textbf{Response 2}\\
\midrule
Treatment 1 & 0.0003262 & 0.562 \\
Treatment 2 & 0.0015681 & 0.910 \\
Treatment 3 & 0.0009271 & 0.296 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Table caption}
\end{table}
\end{frame}

%------------------------------------------------

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Theorem}
\begin{theorem}[Mass--energy equivalence]
$E = mc^2$
\end{theorem}
\end{frame}
    
\begin{frame}[fragile] % Need to use the fragile option when verbatim is used in the slide
\frametitle{Verbatim}
\begin{example}[Theorem Slide Code]
\begin{verbatim}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Theorem}
\begin{theorem}[Mass--energy equivalence]
$E = mc^2$
\end{theorem}
\end{frame}\end{verbatim}
\end{example}
\end{frame}

%------------------------------------------------

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Figure}
Uncomment the code on this slide to include your own image from the same directory as the template .TeX file.
%\begin{figure}
%\includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{test}
%\end{figure}
\end{frame}

%------------------------------------------------

\begin{frame}[fragile] % Need to use the fragile option when verbatim is used in the slide
\frametitle{Citation}
An example of the \verb|\cite| command to cite within the presentation:\\~

This statement requires citation \cite{p1}.
\end{frame}

%------------------------------------------------

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{References}
\footnotesize{
\begin{thebibliography}{99} % Beamer does not support BibTeX so references must be inserted manually as below
\bibitem[Smith, 2012]{p1} John Smith (2012)
\newblock Title of the publication
\newblock \emph{Journal Name} 12(3), 45 -- 678.
\end{thebibliography}
}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Specify the horizontal size of the sidebar:

```
\setbeamersize{text margin left=30mm,text margin right=30mm}
```

The *beamer* pack­age doc­u­men­ta­tion you can find in the following link:
[The beamer class User Guide for version 3.41.](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/beamer) (page 76)

Comment: How can we modify top and bottom?

Comment: @SayOL: Have a look at: [beamer: content top and bottom margins](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/256241/beamer-content-top-and-bottom-margins)

Comment: It will conflict with block and make block left and right space not equal. Is there any other way to change text margin?

Answer (score 2):

The answer by @Bobyandbob is quite useful. Let me make something clear for the newbies like me:

This line needs to be added after the theme declaration. Otherwise, it will not affect anything. Apparently, the \usetheme{} line sets the sizes for Beamer. Thus, to adjust the settings, the adjustments need to be made after the theme declarations.