# Why to waste space above my picture?

Tags: graphics, cv

Here is my [CV](https://gsamaras.files.wordpress.com/2016/02/cv2.pdf), where I have my picture on the "top" right corner. But it's not on top, which OK might be too much, but I would like to be more on top, or to re-configure some things to gain that wasted space above the picture.

This is the code of the picture:

```
\hfill {\em \includegraphics[width=0.16\textwidth]{sam}}
```

and the result is this:

[image]

Is there anything to force it move closer to the top?

I am also using res.cls, but I didn't find something there, with my inexperienced eyes, that could help. I have it [here](https://gsamaras.wordpress.com/code/cv-in-latex/).

Comment: Not sure, but maybe `\vspace{}` with a negative number as argument might work. See also [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76101/difference-between-vspace-and-vspace-for-negative-arguments).

Comment: Yeah @MWijnand, that's it! You can answer the question if you want. I had tried that, but without the `*`!!

Comment: is there a reason for that `\em`?  (`\emph{...}` is recommended as the proper latex form when it's called for, but one can't emphasize a picture.)

Comment: I wondered that too @barbarabeeton. It doesn't make a difference if it's there or not. No idea why it's there, since that CV started its life some years ago. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `\vspace*{}` with a negative number as argument. See also [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76101/difference-between-vspace-and-vspace-for-negative-arguments).

Answer (score 4):

You can make a tikzpicture and place the figure "on top" of your document as so:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \node at (current page.north)[anchor=north,inner sep=50pt,xshift = 4cm,
                                      yshift = 0cm]{
        \includegraphics[height=1cm]{resumephoto}
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Just fiddle around with the xshift and yshift to get it in the right position.

Comment: Good idea too!!