# Vertical space before new section on new page begins

Tags: spacing, sectioning

How can you create vertical space before a new section on a new page begins? Using `vspace` or `bigskip` does not work.

Example:

```
\vspace{5mm}
\section{Section 1}
Some text
\subsection{Section 1.1}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `\vspace*{5mm}`?

Comment: Thank you. It works with `vspace*`. What is the problem with `vspace` without *?

Comment: See the link in my answer below.

Comment: Is this a one time thing or do you want this applied to every `\section`? If the latter it would be better to adapt the `\section` command accordingly. (The best way to do this depends on the class you're using.)

Comment: @clemens: This has to be applied to every \section.

Comment: @b4154 then you should state this in your question and also tell your class so people can give you proper advice. Manually adding `\vspace*` is error prone and surely the wrong way to proceed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I stated in a comment, you can use the starred version of `\vspace{...}`, that is:

```
\vspace*{5mm}
\section{Section 1}
Some text
\subsection{Section 1.1}
```

A similar question (and thus answer) is asked here: [difference between \vspace and \vspace* for negative arguments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76101/difference-between-vspace-and-vspace-for-negative-arguments)

This also answers your follow up question.

Comment: Using `\vspace*{5mm}` instead of `\vspace{5mm}` solves the problem. The star is essential.