# How to prevent vertical spacing accumulation?

Tags: spacing, vertical-spacing

By "spacing accumulation", I mean the resulting spacing when two `\vspace{}` commands meet.

For example, let's say you set an after-skip for the figure environment and a before-skip for a chapter section. When these two skips meet, they will produce a double-spacing.

I know [`\vspace{}` will always discard the skip at the start of the page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/76106/234832). This is not the issue here.

Comment: I guess you want `\addvspace`

Comment: chapter headings normally prevent floats above, and environments use `\addvspace` which should prevent build up

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want `\addvspace` which avoids stacking. However, what you describe (figure before chapter heading) shouldn't happen, unless you are doing something very evil in the background.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[t]{2cm}
X\dotfill X

\vspace{3cm}
\vspace{2cm}
X\dotfill X
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{2cm}
X\dotfill X

\addvspace{3cm}
\addvspace{2cm}
X\dotfill X
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{2cm}
X\dotfill X

\vspace{3cm}
X\dotfill X
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]